# appending data to hbase table from a spark rdd using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, rdd

I am trying to add data to a HBase Table. I have done the following so far:

```
def convert (a:Int,s:String) : Tuple2[ImmutableBytesWritable,Put]={
                        val p = new Put(a.toString.getBytes())
                        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("ColumnFamily"),Bytes.toBytes("col_2"), s.toString.getBytes())//a.toString.getBytes())
                        println("the value of a is: " + a)
                        new Tuple2[ImmutableBytesWritable,Put](new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes(a)), p);
                   }
new PairRDDFunctions(newrddtohbaseLambda.map(x=>convert(x, randomstring))).saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConfig)
```

newrddtohbaseLambda is this:

```
val x = 12
val y = 15
val z = 25
val newarray = Array(x,y,z)
val newrddtohbaseLambda = sc.parallelize(newarray)
```

"randomstring" is this

```
val randomstring = "abc, xyz, dfg"
```

Now, what this does is, it adds abc,xyz,dfg to rows 12, 15 and 25 after deleting the already present values in these rows. I want that value to be present and add abc,xyz,dfg instead replace. How can I get it done? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: Hey, I am trying to append data to HBase table instead of replacing the existing data every time function "convert" is called. "convert" takes two parameters, what row to put data into and what data to put. In this case, the data is to be appended in rows 12,15 and 25 and the data which is to be appended is  a string "abc,xyz,dfg". Currently, it replaces the already present strings in these rows but I want it to append. I hope this makes it clear. Kindly ask if further clarifications are needed. Thanks

Comment: HBase is a key value store, if you want to append data to existing table, you need to pass the unique key, otherwise it will update the existing record.